# Slick/HikariCP/MySQL Always Timing Out

Tags: scala, jdbc, playframework, slick, hikaricp

I am using Play (2.6) with Slick, my database connection times out every second or third try. The only way to get the connection up again is by restarting the app with `sbt run`. It's driving me crazy, any help appreciated.

To be clear, I'm using Slick with a local MySQL database for very lightweight usage.

**build.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.11"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.2.3"
```

**application.conf**

```
# db connections = ((physical_core_count * 2) + effective_spindle_count)
fixedConnectionPool = 5

repository.dispatcher {
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  throughput = 1
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = ${fixedConnectionPool}
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: <dbconfig> - Connection is not available, request timed out after 1001ms.
```

Stack Trace:

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:548)
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186)
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:145)
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:83)
slick.jdbc.hikaricp.HikariCPJdbcDataSource.createConnection(HikariCPJdbcDataSource.scala:14)
slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.<init>(JdbcBackend.scala:453)
slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:46)
slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.createSession(JdbcBackend.scala:37)
slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(BasicBackend.scala:249)
slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession$(BasicBackend.scala:248)
slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.acquireSession(JdbcBackend.scala:37)
slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(BasicBackend.scala:274)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Update**

I didn't include the specific db config in application.conf:

```
<name> {
  slick.driver = scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver
  driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
  url = __
  user = __
  password = __
}
```

I've added to the config:

```
  keepAliveConnection = true
  connectionPool = disabled
```

And it's working fine.

Comment: It sounds like you are not closing connections in your code. Closing is what returns the connection to the pool, as a result your connection pool has probably run out of available connections. Or you are using more concurrently than connections available in the pool. Without more information, we can't possibly tell.

Comment: Yes, I had seen the error that I had too many connections. Please see update to my question. Why does my fix work? Because I'm reusing the same connection?

Comment: Your fix works, because you are now not using a connection pool and just creating connections when needed. If you really have a connection leak, this means you may eventually run into errors with your database server running out of connections. BTW, it was not _per [my] comment_: this 'fix' was not my suggestion.